# Resizing and Saving GeoTIFF into JPG(JGW)

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, jpg

I want to resize a batch GeoTIFF files into 1062*1653, and save the batch GeoTIFF into JPG (associated with JGW).

I tried resize one TIFF in QGIS, but how do I apply the whole action to 8000 GeoTIFF files or are there any more straightforward ways that I can resize the JPG and produce an updated JGW file?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: do you know about [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#gdal-translate)?

Comment: What do you mean by "resize". What are the number of rows and columns in the original? And second question, in order to process 8000 files, what scripting language are you familiar with?

Comment: @Micha the original size is 1417(columns)*2205(rows), and I need to resize them into 1062*1653, eventually convert the GeoTIFF into JPG (associated with JGW file).

Comment: @IanTurton Hi Ian, yes I heard of this tool before, but didn't know how to apply it to a batch file. Right now I am able to resize the GeoTIFF in QGIS one by one, then convert the batch GeoTIFF into JPG using GlobalMapper.

Comment: I'd read up on how to use gdal and then worry about the batch steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your required new size is very nearly the same ratio as the original so what you want to do is  upsampling to a slightly lower resolution. As @IanTurton pointed out, gdal_translate is a good option.

As for doing 8000 images in a batch, there are numerous ways to choose from, depending on what you are familiar with. At the simple level, you can do a loop on the command line (bash in Linux, or cmd in Windows). A simple Python script also be used with the GDAL bindings to Python. You could choose to prepare a model in QGIS.

Comment: Thank you @Micha ! These are raw aerial images and I tried the gdal_translate, but then there is rotation issue coming up. Images started to rotated obviously and distorted a lot when processing to the 10th image.